# How do I save two models related with OneToOne in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one

Here is my code:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Person(models.Model):

        user                = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
        title               = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PERSON_TITLE_CHOICES)
        first_name          = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Basically, what I want to do, is when I am registering a new user, I'd like to save a Person model, already with the relation to the User.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here. You can either register a post-save hook for User and create your Person there, or you can create them together. I do the latter. Just make sure you wrap them in a transaction so if one fails, the other does also:

```
with django.db.transaction.commit_on_success():
    user = User(...)
    user.save()
    person = Person(user = user, ...)
    person.save()
```

Comment: Can you provide the full code/context to your solution please?  I am unsure if this is in a models.py, view, or elsewhere